# plotly go.bar add legend for categorical colour variable

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use go.bar to make subplot bar graphs. I want to colour the bars by the categorical materials variable. I have managed to this, but also want a shared legend between the subplots showing the color by material.

```
materials=['food', 'flowers', 'chess', 'garden', 'kitchen']
x=['browns', 'highes', 'jacks', 'johns', 'harrys']
y=[1,3,5,6,7]
x2=['trevors', 'elens', 'georges', 'marias', 'franks']
y2=[3,7,8,9,5]
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
color_map = {'food':'red',
      'flowers':'blue',
      'chess':'yellow',
      'garden':'green',
      'kitchen':'grey'}
colors = [color_map[category] for category in materials]
fig.add_trace(
go.Bar(x=x,
      y=y,
   # name=materials,
    marker_color=colors),
row=1, col=1
)
fig.add_trace(
go.Bar(x=x2,
      y=y2,
   # name=materials,
    marker_color=colors),
row=2, col=1
)
fig.show()
```

This is what it currently looks like:
[image]

how can I get the legend to show the bars are coloured by material?

Comment: You have five category and five material categories, I am not understanding the point of  the legend

Answer (score 0):

If you want to categorise the legend by the colour of each material, you need to use a process that draws a graph for each material. The legend will show the legend for the upper graph and the legend for the lower graph with the same legend name. Clicking on the legend in this state will show or hide it in the graph. Having the same legend may cause confusion. To avoid this, it is possible to group the legends. There is also a way to remove duplicate legends.
We don't know what your end goal is, so try adding groupings or removing duplicate legends. The code for each grouping and removing duplicates is commented so you can unlock it and check the results.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

materials=['food', 'flowers', 'chess', 'garden', 'kitchen']
x=['browns', 'highes', 'jacks', 'johns', 'harrys']
y=[1,3,5,6,7]
x2=['trevors', 'elens', 'georges', 'marias', 'franks']
y2=[3,7,8,9,5]
fig = make_subplots(rows=3, cols=1)
color_map = {'food':'red',
      'flowers':'blue',
      'chess':'yellow',
      'garden':'green',
      'kitchen':'grey'}
colors = [color_map[category] for category in materials]

for i in range(len(materials)):
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[x[i]],
                         y=[y[i]],
                         name=materials[i],
                         # legendgroup='group1',
                         # legendgrouptitle=dict(text='Materials'),
                         marker_color=colors[i]),
                  row=1, col=1
                 )
    fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=[x2[i]],
                         y=[y2[i]],
                         name=materials[i],
                         # legendgroup='group2',
                         # legendgrouptitle=dict(text='Materials'),
                         marker_color=colors[i]),
                  row=2, col=1)

# Removal of duplicate legends.
# names = set()
# fig.for_each_trace(
#     lambda trace:
#         trace.update(showlegend=False)
#         if (trace.name in names) else names.add(trace.name))

fig.show()
```

[image]